# authority_uri_insecure error while utilizing Azure B2C in angular application

Tags: angular, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I've configured everything that is needed for authenticating my angular SPA via Azure B2C by Google authentication provider. All of the definitions of domains and urls are using SSL (https), i.e. redirect uri is `https://localhost:4200` etc.

App registration was defined as described in [the following tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-app-registration). All app registration endpoints in Azure are also `https` but while utilizing the authentication as described in [the following tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular) whenever injecting the MSAL in the actual app page I receive the following exception:
code: authority_uri_insecure
desc: Authority URIs must use https.
and I can't figure out what is wrong with my definitions.

I tried both actual tenant ID as the `authority` definition for `MsalModule` registration in the angular app and `organizations` but both issue the same exception.

Any help?

Comment: Is that you run the application on your local machine? If so, have you configured SSL certificate for `localhost`. If you do not do that, please change your redirect URL as `http`.

Comment: The documentation linked is specific to AAD. The guidance for AAD B2C is here: [Register SPA App](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-spa). Then follow the AAD B2C SPA PKCE app sample from [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-b2c-javascript-spa). You can find the MSAL specific config for AAD B2C [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-b2c-overview). The authority URL will be in the format `https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_susi`. Let us know if you still have trouble.

Comment: @JimXu
I have configured the SSL locally and this is why I'm using the `https`. Also please pay attention to the fact that the infra asks the `authority` to be `secure` and this is why I've made all the arrangements to utilize SSL locally, othewise it won't work at all.
I want to understand what am I missing? What is NOT configured in a secure manner from the MSAL standpoint? Or maybe this is a false positive exception?

Comment: @Lentyai Could you please provide the config file?

Comment: @JimXu Which configuration file do you want me to provide?

Comment: I want  to know how you configure B2C in your application?

Comment: @JimXu All the configurations were made by UI tooling on Azure B2C. Do you want the Manifest file generated (automatically) of the app registration or the policy key file generated for Google authentication provider by Azure B2C?

Comment: @Lentyai Have you referred to the sample : https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-angular-v2-samples/angular11-b2c-sample?